# How to make working tree exactly match HEAD? (including removing untracked files)

Tags: git

`git reset --hard HEAD` reverts any changes made to files in the working tree so that they match head.  However, it doesn't touch untracked files.  `git clean -df` removes all untracked local files and directories.

**Is there an easy way to make tracked files match HEAD, and also remove untracked files, that works in all circumstances?**

(You can't run the two commands one after the other, because `git reset --hard HEAD` fails if the repository has no commits.  There's probably some way to check whether the `reset` is necessary, but I imagine it's fiddly.)

I think this is an equivalent question: how can I make my working tree identical[*] to the result of a fresh `git clone` of the repository?

[*] I'm happy for ignored files to be untouched.

Comment: What you're asking for is exactly a `reset` followed by a `clean`. Why do you think this isn't possible?

Comment: @YuvalAdam In at least one situation, you can't `reset` and then `clean`: if the repository is "empty", the `reset` fails. (I want to turn this into an alias that works in all circumstances.)

Comment: Git repos are not meant to be empty. You can see this in several warnings when working with an empty repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single command for this, but can be achieved like you mentioned using:

```
git reset --hard HEAD && git clean -fdx
```

in succession. This might not work for empty repositories, but empty repositories aren't exactly first-class citizens in git (i.e. cloning an empty repo will yield a warning).

If you must have this work for empty repos, simple flip the commands:

```
git clean -fdx && git reset --hard HEAD
```

`clean` should run in any case, and the `reset` can fail without consequence.

Comment: To make a first-class-citizen empty ref, `git mktree </dev/null | xargs git commit-tree | xargs git update-ref refs/heads/master`.